# Playback of videos uploaded to S3 using expo-av

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, video, expo

I am using Expo's ImagePicker library in my react native app to allow users to upload images and videos to a newsfeed. I upload those files to an S3 bucket for retrieval later. Images work fine. I can use the S3 URI in the Image tag and it displays properly. I can also use the local file representation for a preview of the image before uploading. I can't seem to get the same thing to work for video. If I click the provided URL in S3 which ends in the key (something like 03bd4eea26a58b6f35136877d31925a7) it downloads as expected. If I append an extension like .mov to the downloaded file, voila it plays. But if I use that uri in expo-av Video tag nothing shows up.

The ImagePick function looks like (removing some unnecessary parts):

```
  async PickImage(type) {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
            base64: true,
          });
          if (!result.canceled) {


      if (!result.assets[0]?.fileSize) {
        alert("Can't determine the file size. Please choose another image/video");
        this.setState({please_wait_comment: false, please_wait_post: false, please_wait_profile: false});
      } else if (!this.isLessThanTheMB(result.assets[0].fileSize, 250)) {
        alert("The image/video must be smaller than 250MB");
        this.setState({please_wait_comment: false, please_wait_post: false, please_wait_profile: false});
      } else {
            const base64String = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.assets[0].uri, {
                encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
             });
              const buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64");
                this.setState({post_image: buffer, post_image_uri: result.assets[0].uri}, () => {this.setState({please_wait_post: false})});
              }
    }
          }
}
```

On my node side I have:

```
    async function generateUploadURL() {
        const rawBytes = await randomBytes(16);
        const imageName = rawBytes.toString('hex');
        const params = ({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: imageName,
            Expires: 60
        })

        const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
        return uploadURL;
    }
```

I tried adding the ContentType option and set it to video/quicktime for example but it didn't make a difference - the "type" was still blank in S3. If I manually upload a file, it recognizes the type and I can then cut-and-paste the S3 URI into the  tag and it works - renders in my app fine. I should be using Cloudfront I guess...so that's next but I will still have to ensure the type is correct in order for this to work - so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's your headers, which needs to be "Content-Type","video/mp4". Using XMLHttpRequest, you could do something like this:

```
const PickImage = async(type) => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
        base64: true,
      });
      if (!result.canceled) {


  if (!result.assets[0]?.fileSize) {
    /*
    */
  } else if (!this.isLessThanTheMB(result.assets[0].fileSize, 250)) {
     /*
    */
  } else {
        const base64String = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.assets[0].uri, {
            encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
         });
          const buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, "base64");

          /* NEW */
          await pickImageUpload(buffer);

          }
}
      }
}


/* NEW */
const pickImageUpload = async(localBuffer) =>{

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.open("PUT", YOUR-AWS-SIGNED-URL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('Successfully uploaded to S3');
            } else {
                console.log('Error while sending to S3')
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.send(localBuffer);

}
```